# Justification of whole text in Ms Word which created by programatically

Tags: c#, methods, ms-word, com-interop, text-justify

i want to arrange the document i created dynamically in ms word like whole text justification(right and left side). but shall i do it when Word Open Method or Word SaveAs2 method. i looked up mirosoft website for which method for whole text justifying (left and right) but cant see anything except paragraph alignment. i dont want paragraph alignment all word range will be justified when i open the doc in ms word 
Open Method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open.aspx and for SaveAs2 Method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas2.aspx all of these method dont contain a 'ref object' for Justifying

such as the code below i write; doesnt contain a ref Object for Justifying Whole Text

```
object Unknown=Type.Missing;
object Source=(File Source Destiny);

object encoding=Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8;
object noEncodingDialog=false;

doc=newApp.Open(ref Source,ref Unknown,
ref Unknown,ref Unknown,ref Unknown,
ref Unknown,ref Unknown,ref Unknown,
ref Unknown,ref Unknown,ref encoding,
ref Unknown,ref Unknown,ref Unknown,ref noEncodingDialog,ref Unknown);
```

Answer (score 1):

i looked up to microsoft website and saw that;

```
doc.Paragraps.Alignment=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphJustify;
```

Solved..

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
    Range content = doc.Content;
    Paragraph pText = content.Paragraphs.Add();                    
    pText.Range.Text = "sadfsadfsda"
    pText.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
```